# Geo Spatial Analysis in Pyspark ( Point in a Polygon)

Tags: pyspark, geospatial

I have a use case where Im given 4 geo spatial Point sets  that represents 4 rectangles . I have a table which has a point( which is just a latitude and longitude ) . My task is to check if the point in the table lies within any of the four rectangles.

This should be done in Pyspark . I tried this using udf's but its taking a long time as the main table contains lot of rows. Could anyone help me on how to efficiently solve this problem in Pyspark.

Right now I have used Shapely to help me with Point and Polygon creations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of the rectangle as space bounded by `(min_latitude, max_latitude)` and `(min_longitude, max_longitude)`. Let's assume your point-of-interest is `x = (lat, lon)`. Now, for each rectangle you need to check whether `min_latitude <=x <= max_latitude` and `min_longitude <= y <= max_longitude`. These can be done using native spark functions, no udf is required. Also, before performing these operations, you can select only required columns (dataframe.select(cols...)) from your original dataframe to discard redundant information.